# Bootstrap 3 - Header has magical white space in browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, header

So I was trying to make my header a solid color of maroon, but there seems to be white space on top of it. Looks really ugly. Another stackoverflow member told me to set the body to margin:0px; It works in the jsfiddle he gave me, but when I apply it to my website it doesnt. If it helps I'm using xampp and Mozilla as my browser.

[image]

How do I go about fixing this? Tried manipulating headers and stuff but to no avail.

```css
/* bootstrap 3 helpers */

.navbar-form input,
.form-inline input {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
/* Create a medium height at 40px */

.navbar-md {
  min-height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand,
.navbar-md .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-brand {
  height: 40px
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 6px 12px 6px 0px;
  padding: 6px 7px 6px 7px;
}
.navbar-md .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 19px;
}
.container#slider {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.container-full#headerC {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #8F1925;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.navbar-header {
  background-image: url("bootstraplogo.png", "bootstraplogoslice1.png") background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 479px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto auto;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    height: 45px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .navbar-header {
    background-size: auto 50px, 1px 50px;
  }
  .navbar-md#header {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
/* RESPONSIVE HEADER*/

.container-header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.text-center {
  
}

p#headerP {
  display: inherit;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #76141D;
  font-family: "Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #fff;
}
p#subheader {
  display: inherit;
  margin: 0;

  padding: 0 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #E72635;
}

.p img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

/*  */
/* Custom container */
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
 }
header {
  margin: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<head>
    <title>The University Digest</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-full" id="headerC">
  
   <header class="masthead">

 
     <p id="headerP">The University Digest</p>
     <p id="subheader">The Official Student Publication of Western Mindanao State University</p>
   </header>
  
 </div>

<!-- Navigation -->
 <div id="nav">
   <div class=" navbar-custom navbar navbar-inverse navbar-md">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse navbar-md">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Articles <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Article</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Comics</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Editorial Cartoon</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Uncensored</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Publications<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Magazine</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tejido</a>
    </li>
     </ul>
     <li><a href="#">Applications</a>
   </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">The Staff<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Editorial Board</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">By-Laws</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">WMSU Portal</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
    </li>
   </li>
   </ul> 
  </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In the snippet it's gone, but when I run it vial localhost it's there ! MAGICAL!

Comment: try this body{padding:0;margin:0}

Comment: Depending on how your page is encoded, you might have a [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the top of the page. If you have something like Notepad++, change the encoding to "UTF-8 without BOM" and see if the space goes away.

Comment: FYI: it seems havign an extra </ul> in your code. will be good if you remove it. it will not solve the prob though.

Comment: Thank you very much! @akash 's advice did the trick.

Comment: Thank you also Tieson and PHJCJO for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> body{ padding:0;margin:0 }

Answer by user @Akash

Thank you so much! :)